# optimizar busqueda Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hola tengo esta funcion en un servicio de angular la cual funciona bien, pero tarda aveces demasiado en responser de hecho bloquea por pocos segundos la ventana del usuario cuando por ejemplo busco coincidencias por pocos digitos(oviamente devuelve mas resultados), la pregunta es como se podria hacer este procedimiento mas rapido usando lo que provee angular, o como se podria mejorar esta funcion

```
municipiosColombia = ['uno','dos','tres']; // hay 994 elementos
    getLikeTown(termino:string){
        let municipios:any[] = [];
          termino = termino.toLowerCase();

          for (let municipio of this.municipiosColombia){
            let nombre = municipio.toLowerCase();
           if (nombre.indexOf(termino) >= 0) {
            municipios.push(municipio);
           }
          }

     return municipios;

  }
```

Comment: invoco esta funcion en el metodo keyup de un input, deberia mejor crear un boton y esperar que el usuario termine de escribir?

Comment: Si vas a usar "Any", ¿tiene sentido usar Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres mejorar el rendimiento lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar un  `for loop`, actualmente estas usando un `for of`, este junto con el `for in` no se comparan con el `for loop`, es mas, las funciones comunes de filtro como lo son `reduce/filter/map` siguen teniendo un rendimiento deficiente comparado con `for loop` pero en lo personal son mis opciones a la hora de hacer un filtro, en particular la función `filter`

a continuación te muestro un código con el uso de `filter`

```
municipiosColombia = ['uno','dos','tres']; // hay 994 elementos
    getLikeTown(termino:string){

          termino = termino.toLowerCase();
          const municipios:any[] = this.municipiosColombia.filter((municipio) => {
              return municipio.toLowerCase().includes(termino);
          });

     return municipios;

  }
```

y bueno el código que debería tener mejor rendimiento, `for loop`

```
municipiosColombia = ['uno','dos','tres']; // hay 994 elementos
getLikeTown(termino: string) {
  termino = termino.toLowerCase();
  const municipios = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.municipiosColombia.length; i++) {
    if(this.municipiosColombia[i].indexOf(termino) > -1 ) {
      municipios.push(this.municipiosColombia[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

PD: `includes` e `indexOf` funcionan igual con la diferencia que `includes` te reconoce comparaciones con `NaN` y `undefined` y te retorna directamente `true` o `false`. También considerar que `includes` no está soportado en IE

PD2: con respecto a tu pregunta de si usarlo en `keyup` o en un botón, debería ser en `keyup` por temas de experiencia de usuario a menos que en verdad sea muy lenta la ejecución en ese caso tendrías que buscar otra solución como por ejemplo la del botón